# Why am I getting a CS1502 (invalid arguments) error from this code?

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2012

I'm facing this issue and I don't know the reason behind it. Here's the error Visual Studio is reporting:

> The best overloaded method match for 'PostForum.INSERTforum(int, string, string, System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments

I'm using Oracle to store my data and also created a procedure called INSERTFORUM. I am not sure if I have a problem with the stored procedure or something else. Please help me sort out this issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Forum : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string course_Id = DropDownList1.Text;
        int ccourse_Id = Convert.ToInt32(course_Id);
        string question = TextBox1.Text;
        string posterName = TextBox2.Text;
        DateTime blog_date = DateTime.Now;
        PostForum.INSERTforum(course_Id, question, posterName, blog_date);
    }
}
```

Code for :Postforum.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class PostForum
{
    public static int INSERTforum(int course_Id, string question, string posterName, DateTime blog_date)
    {
        int rowsAffected = 0;

        using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERTforum", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add("@course_Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = course_Id;
            command.Parameters.Add("@question", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = question;
            command.Parameters.Add("@posterName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = posterName;
            command.Parameters.Add("@blog_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = blog_date;

            rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return rowsAffected;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERTforum` expects an int as the first parameter. You're passing it a string. Correct your invocation of `INSERTforum` to read:

```
PostForum.INSERTforum(ccourse_Id, question, posterName, blog_date);
```

Note that this will fail if `DropDownList1.Text` can't be parsed as an integer.

Don't forget to look at the Error List tab in Visual Studio. The error you saw was only the first - the next error would have given you the information I did.